# deviceQuery to find GPU specs on Mac

Tags: macos, cuda, nvidia

This is the CUDA install path on my mac

```
 /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/
```

I'm trying to run deviceQuery as per the following instructions:

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/#axzz3tC8ceEPF

however the x86_64 directory doesn't exist inside my bin directory.

Where, as in which directory can I run deviceQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the samples first, as described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/#compiler-verification). The process of building the samples should create whatever is needed inside the **samples** bin directory.

After you have built the samples, note that this: `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/` is **not** the install path. This: `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/` is the install path. The samples are located here: `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/samples/` and the samples bin directory is here: `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/samples/bin/`

(This: `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/` is the tools bin directory.  Not the same as the samples bin directory.)

Comment: /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin//bin/nvcc -ccbin clang++ -I../../common/inc  -m64  -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -o asyncAPI.o -c asyncAPI.cu
make[1]: /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin//bin/nvcc: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [asyncAPI.o] Error 1
make: *** [0_Simple/asyncAPI/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2

Comment: This is what I get when I run make inside the samples directory.

Comment: Because this: `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin//bin/nvcc` is wrong.  Note the double occurrence of `bin//bin` which is not correct.  You have entered a path incorrectly during setup of the CUDA install.  If you were prompted for the install path and you entered `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin`, that was incorrect.

Comment: Fixed that now, but getting this error. error: unable to open output file 'asyncAPI.o': 'Permission denied'
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [asyncAPI.o] Error 1
make: *** [0_Simple/asyncAPI/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2

Comment: You have to build the samples as a root user, since they are storing their results in a location that an ordinary user does not have access to (in this case -- it depends on where you have installed the samples and where you are building to.)

Comment: clang++  -rpath /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib -L/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib -framework CUDA -o clock_nvrtc clock.o  -lnvrtc
ld: framework not found CUDA
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [clock_nvrtc] Error 1
make: *** [0_Simple/clock_nvrtc/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2

Comment: This is what I get using sudo.

Comment: These are all separate issues (right?).  If you want to run deviceQuery, why not follow the instructions and build deviceQuery.  It's covered in the document section I linked:  `make -C 1_Utilities/deviceQuery`  Isn't that what your question is about?  "deviceQuery to find GPU specs on Mac"  And if you actually want to build all the samples, just use `make -k`  It will continue on and build all the samples it is capable of.  If you then actually care about the clock_nvrtc sample and it's not getting built, you can come back and ask a question about it.